# Не работает "! + tab" в vs code для HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Узнал что в VS code можно автоматически создать базовую структуру программы через сочетание клавиш "**! + tab**", но у меня это сочетание почему то не работает, если я пропишу просто "**! + tab**" то таб сделает отступ вправо и все, если пропишу "**<! + tab**" тогда появится лишь строка "**<!DOCTYPE html**" и ничего более, почему так? Скажите пожалуйста

Comment: Скачал сегодня последнюю версию и не работает " shift + ! " - в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверь настройки 'emmet', вдруг ты каким-либо образом их менял.
В крайнем случае можешь использовать `html:5` + `Tab`.

Так же рекомендую использовать одну из последних версий VS Code.

Comment: html:5 + tab сработал да
В настройках прописал "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true" и заработало "! + tab"

Answer (score 0):

Добавь эти две строчки в json файл

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"files.associations": { "*html": "html" }
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

В параметрах Emmet я установил галочку na **Emmet: Trigger Expansion on Tab**.

Заработало "!+Tab".

Comment: зачем дублировать неоднократно написанные в ответах?

Answer (score -1):

В настройках прописал `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true`

при `! + tab` не получилось, а `html:5 + tab` сработал.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

У меня такой сбой произошел, когда начал изучать React, установил Babel и стал писать код с JSX. Может быть это как-то связано одно с другим? Просто отследил, что именно тогда отвалилась возможность создать структуру html документа через ! + tab